# Setting user id automatically on POST in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to POST a "record" using Django REST. I want Django to automagically set the user id from the logged in user.

views.py:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'owner', 'desc')
        read_only_fields = ('owner',)
```

models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('appserver.MyUser', related_name='appserver')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

I am using EmailAbstractUser from django-rest-authemail 0.1.4:

views.py:

```
class MyUser(EmailAbstractUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('Date of birth', null=True, blank=True)
    objects = EmailUserManager()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you have to first set the instance of the user using the request.user

Comment: these are just your models - where is your POSTing code?

Comment: When I try to post it tells me that I explicitly needs to set the owner_id, so the problem isn't really in the POST AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

You can overwrite the perform_create method in your ItemViewSet, something like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

If you want to set this attribute to the requesting user, only at creation time, you will be set now.
But, if you want to re-set the owner at updating time too, you'll have to overwrite the perform_update method too (in the same way).

Comment: Hi, I added this to my ItemViewSet try this but still gets "owner_id cannot be null". I've changed my code above to reflect this.

Comment: You should add a permission class to your viewset, that enforces the user to be authenticated to access it. Otherwise, self.request.user could be an anonymous user...

Answer (score 0):

OK I actually solved this myself:

In the ItemSerializer in serializers.py:

```
owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.id')
```

In Item in models.py

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
```

In ItemViewSet in views.py:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.owner = self.request.user
```